# strtok fail at finding new line character ("\n")

Tags: c, strtok, trendline

Here is the function:

```
int parse_headers(c_request *req, char *raw_headers) {
    char *command_line;
    char *raw_header;

    req->headers = NULL;

    command_line = strtok_r(raw_headers, "\\n", &raw_headers);
    printf("command line = [%s]\n", command_line);
    if (parse_command(req, command_line) < 0)
        return -1;
    while ((raw_header = strtok_r(raw_headers, "\\n", &raw_headers))) {
        printf("\nraw header = [%s]\n", raw_header);
        parse_header(req, raw_header);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

***raw_headers*** equal :

```
POST www.google.fr HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)\nHost: www.tutorialspoint.com\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\nContent-Length: 38\nAccept-Language: en-us\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?
```

So `strtok` find the first `\n` (`command_line` equal `POST www.google.fr HTTP/1.1`), but in the while loop, when I print the `raw_header`, it print me `raw header = [User-Age]` instead of `raw header = [User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)]`

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: `command_line = strtok_r(raw_headers, "\\n", &raw_headers);` is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The delimiter `"\\n"` specified for `strtok_r` consists of two characters: `'\\'` and `'n'`. There is a `n` after `User-Age`, so the data is cut there.

You should use `"\n"` to have `strtok_r` search for LF.

If you actually want to separate the data by a multi-charcter string `"\\n"`, then `strtok_r` is not for that. You should do it manually, maybe using [`strstr()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html).

Comment: How can i use strstr to have same result as strtok ? thanks again @MikeCAT

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.... you are using a delimiter formed by a backslash (`\`) and the character `n`, not a new line (new line has to be written as `\n`, not `\\n`.  You can try to check how it parses a string with n's or backslashes, and you'll see how it breaks the string at these two characters.